# React Router persistant company in URL path and dynamic change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to move from having current active `companyId` in query params to URL path.

- `http://localhost:3000/1?companyId=comp1`
- `http://localhost:3000/2?companyId=comp1`

To

- `http://localhost:3000/comp1/1`
- `http://localhost:3000/comp1/2`

So basically:

1. User Auth it's self in Login screen.
2. Then selects a company from list to work with / see data in `Page1` and `Page2`
3. With specific company selected `Page1` and `Page2` should be loaded, and that company selected should continue to be in URL

   http://localhost:3000/comp1/1

   http://localhost:3000/comp1/2

Initial idea i had is to store selected company in state and then on state change change the `basename` but that does not work, i can't access `Page*`

Main App

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useStoreRoutes } from '../../states/useStoreRoutes'
import { PrivateRoutes } from './components/PrivateRoutes'
import { PublicRoutes } from './components/PublicRoutes'

export const ReactRouter = () => {
  const currentOrg = useStoreRoutes((s) => s.currentOrg)

  return (
    <>
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + currentOrg}>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '10px' }}>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
          <Link to="/compList">Comp List</Link>

          <Link to="/1">Page 1</Link>
          <Link to="/2">Page 2</Link>
        </div>

        <RoutesComp />
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

const RoutesComp = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoutes component={Page1} path="/1" />
      <PrivateRoutes component={Page2} path="/2" />

      <PublicRoutes component={Login} path="/login" />
      <PublicRoutes component={CompList} path="/compList" />
      <PublicRoutes component={Home} path="/" />
    </Switch>
  )
}

const Home = () => <h2>Home</h2>
const Login = () => <h2>Login</h2>
const CompList = () => {
  const currentOrgSet = useStoreRoutes((s) => s.currentOrgSet)
  return (
    <h2>
      <Link to="/comp1" onClick={() => currentOrgSet('comp1')}>
        Comp1
      </Link>
      <Link to="/comp2" onClick={() => currentOrgSet('comp2')}>
        Comp2
      </Link>
    </h2>
  )
}
const Page1 = () => <h2>Page 1</h2>
const Page2 = () => <h2>Page 2</h2>
```

State

```
import create from 'zustand'

export const useStoreRoutes = create((set: any) => {
  return {
    currentOrg: '',
    currentOrgSet: (data: string) => set({ currentOrg: data }),
  }
})
```

PrivateRoutes

```
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom'

export const db = [
  {
    companyId: 'comp1',
  },
  {
    companyId: 'comp2',
  },
  {
    companyId: 'comp3',
  },
]

export const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const getCompId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
  const checkIfCompIsInUser = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
      const el = db[i]

      if (el.companyId === getCompId) {
        console.log(true)
        return true
      } else {
        console.log(false)
        return false
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Route
      render={(props: any) =>
        checkIfCompIsInUser() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

PublicRoute

```
import { Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom'

export const PublicRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render={(props: any) => <Component {...props} />} />
}
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow, but do you just need a route with a path like `path="/:company/1` and another with `path="/:company/2` for the page components? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that we could inspect and debug with live?

Comment: Have not tried this specific way will need to look into it, but i think yes this is what i need. So basically user log's in, then he/she gets list of companies that they can work with. So when choosing that company it will be set as active in URL. Its similar to what JIRA has with organization but instead of subdomain i need this in path

Comment: I don't think you need any state for this. When you have the list of companies you can create the link right there with the appropriate company value in the link path. It may or may not be the best thing for you, but that's also why I asked if you could provide us a running sandbox to play around with.

Comment: Created codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-jackson-sxysw3?file=/src/App.tsx for now ignore login part and just go straight to Comp List

Comment: Main thing is that i just want to set the 1st level of the URL Path / SubDir to that company i have selected. But also i'm trying to set this like globally so then i don't have to go and change all the links

Comment: What *should* the page1 and page2 links look like if there's no selected company yet? The seem to be dependent on a `companyId`. The links from the companyList make sense because you have the company ids there, but the page 1 and 2 links in the header seem out-of-place.

Comment: If no company selected then redirect to Comp List to select company

Comment: Think of the page1 or page2 just some specific data that relates to that company, so example, when i click on page1 then i can use API request to select the active company i'm currently using from URL path to fetch it's data and display on page1/2

Comment: imagine that Page1 is CompanyEmployeeList and Page2 is CompanyOtherData. So for example on CompanyEmployeeList you would only list for that specific company and not the other one. It's all about selecting specific company and displaying that companies data by just using API that when making request for specific company i can take from URL path.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you need to declare the `Page1` and `Page2` routes to use a dynamic path that includes the `companyId`.

```
const RoutesComp = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoutes component={Page1} path="/:companyId/1" />
      <PrivateRoutes component={Page2} path="/:companyId/2" />

      <PublicRoutes component={Login} path="/login" />
      <PublicRoutes component={CompList} path="/compList" />
      <PublicRoutes component={Home} path="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

From here you can fix the `PrivateRoutes` custom route component to read the route match params for checking access.

```
export const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  return (
    <Route
      render={(props: any) => {
        const { companyId } = props.match.params;
        const checkIfCompIsInUser = () => {
          return db.some((el) => el.companyId === companyId);
        };
        return checkIfCompIsInUser() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        );
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

Example `CompanyList` to render links to each company's page 1 and 2.

```
const CompList = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/comp1/1">Comp1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/comp1/2">Comp2</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/comp2/1">Comp1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/comp2/2">Comp2</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-persistant-company-in-url-path-and-dynamic-change]

Comment: Yeah i've done similar to this just now but i was really hoping that i don't need to go thru all the links and add :company because there are a lot of links in my project, hence was looking something globally to set this.

Comment: @Marius Since it seems like all your company page routes essentially "/company/page" you may want to create a single `path="/:companyId/:page"` route and switch on the `page` param, or a single `path="/:companyId"` route then then builds a nested route like `path={\`${path}/:page\`}` where `path` comes from the `useRouteMatch` hook. See the RRDv5 [nesting](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) demo. If you are open to upgrading to RRDv6 building nested routes/links is even easier, just FYI.

Comment: @Marius Oops, I just realized you were referring to the links, not the routes. Yeah, they would necessarily all need to be updated.